# Как устроить перебор переменных из другого файла php?

Tags: php, переменные, include

Есть файл php, например base.php в нем переменные:

```
$perem1='Данные 1';
$perem2='Данные 2';
```

Как в другом файле вывести эти данные перебором?

Что-то типа?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
echo $perem{$i}.' ';
}
```

вывело б = **Данные 1 Данные 2**

Comment: Вы хотите их передать как? Переходом с одной страницы на другую? Или подключая один файл к другому? Или просто отдать на обработку?

Comment: include-ом на второй странице.

Comment: Как в ответе ниже только после инклуда сделайте global $perem;

Comment: @Walfter не обязательно, `include` работает в той-же области видимости что и кусок кода вызвавший его.

Comment: это эксперементирую(учусь) хочу блог сделать, чтоб в одном фале хранить все данные статей и вызывать их сперва список, а потом уже по статейно вытаскивать. Статей максимум 10 будет

Comment: @A.Richard не ну есть еще один вариант, но его не советую, щас добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может имеет смысл в вашем файлике пихать это в массив?

Например вместо:

```
$perem1='Данные 1';
$perem2='Данные 2';
```

Сделать так:

```
$perem[] = 'Данные 1';
$perem[] = 'Данные 2';
```

Тогда мы будем работать как с массивом что позволяет приобрести сразу функциональность и убрать кучу ненужного кода.

P.S. посмотреть можно например `var_dump($perem);`

Или-же вы не управляете файлами?

---

Есть **второй вариант**, более велосипедный (не рекомендую, первый лучше), но, можно вот так:

```
$stack = NULL;
$stack = get_defined_vars();
include('base.php');
$include = array_diff_key(get_defined_vars(), $stack);
var_dump($include);
```

Так вы в `$include` получите массив всех переменных, которые были созданы в `base.php`, где `ключ = название переменной`, `значение = содержимое переменной`.

Но это попахивает диким костылем.

Comment: управляю... это решил сделать как блог без базы данных. чтоб в исходном файле складывать тайтлы, дескрипшены и ссылки, а в другом выводить это все. Сперва весь перечень постов. А потом по ссылке делать выборку на страницу поста

Comment: понял. спасибо. буду осваивать массивы) я их чего-то опасаюсь)) тяжело. но попробую

Comment: @A.Richard массивы наше все, вы их еще полюбите :)

Comment: да, шикарно. оно! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно такой вариант будет справедлив для решения твоей задачи:

```
<?php 
require(__DIR__.'/base.php');
$base [
    'perem1'=>'данные1',
    'perem2'=>'данные2'  
];

foreach ($base as $key => $value) {
   echo "Текущее значение переменной \$key: $value.\n";
}
```